# Performing efficient searches over two columns

Tags: index, optimization

Disclaimer: I am extremely inexperienced with databases, so forgive me if this is an ignorant question.

I have a table which contains several columns, but the ones that are important are the columns containing timestamps and MAC addresses. I need to be able to quickly determine if a certain MAC address appears within a certain range of timestamps. For example lets say I need to see if MAC address 01:02:03:04:05:06 appears in any record on last Monday. Can this be done in sublinear time?

My intuition says that we can construct the timestamp range of interest in logarithmic time, but would we then need to linearly search over this subset of the data to determine if the desired MAC address appears, or can we search for the desired MAC address in logarithmic time?

Does this have anything to do with creating indices? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An index in 2 columns in the order (MACAddress, TimeStamp) will benefit any reasonable query construct for both

1. for a specific MAC address
2. for a MAC address within a range

Why?

- The first query uses "equality" (= MacAddress)
- The second uses "equality" then "inequality" (= MacAddress AND TimeStamp BETWEEN X and Y)

An RDBMS should traverse the index to find the MACAddress quickly, then looks with the subset for the time range.

It should be sublinear performance

Some reading to explain more (SQL Server specific)

- https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/9635.index-selectivity-and-column-order
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797830/how-to-order-fields-on-index-creation-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 1):

When you say *database*, I hope you mean *table*. Imagine your data are written on those 3x5 note cards. If you have no index, all the cards are just dumped in a box. To find anything about MAC addresses and timestamps, you have to examine every card in the box. Very time consuming.

If you index the MAC address, now the cards are in smaller boxes, the boxes themselves are labeled with the MAC address, and they are ordered according to that address. So to find anything about MAC addresses and timestamps, you determine about where in the line of boxes the address you are looking for will be and quickly find the box. But the cards within the box, with the timestamp information, are just dumped in. Again, you have to search every card, but this time you are only looking at the cards associated with the MAC address you are interested in. Finding the box (the MAC address) was very fast but then finding the timestamp was slow but this is some improvement.

If you index the MAC address *and* the timestamp, now you have the boxes in order and the cards within each box are also in order by time. This is the fastest way to find perform a query in the form: find all the times *this* MAC address appears on *this* date?

But suppose you are asked: what were all the MAC addresses that appeared on *this* date? Now you have to search every box for that date. Sure, within each box, the search to find the date (or determine the date is not there) is very quick. But you still have to search every box.

If you create another index just on timestamp, then all the cards are ordered by time. This allows you to quickly find the first MAC address that appears on the date and collect every card until you reach the first card that has the next higher date, at which point you stop.

Creating an index on the timestamp *and* MAC address will not really be an improvement. This will give you a set of boxes in time order but each box will most likely contain only one card (this depends on the precision of the timestamp data type you are using). This illustrates one of the rules of thumb when creating multi-column indexes: they should be listed in order of precision, course to fine.

You *may* gain some incremental improvement (test to find out) by playing a little trick. You have to decrease the precision of the timestamp. This can be done by creating a calculated field that is the timestamp value with the time information stripped away (or set to midnite). This allows you to create boxes with all the cards for each particular day. With an index consisting of this field *and* MAC address, you go to the box for the day you are looking for and the cards within are ordered by address.

So with two indexes, (MAC, timestamp) and (DateOnlyField, MAC), you can quickly answer just about any question you might be asked...concerning MAC address and date, that is.

Keep in mind that the calculated field trick is very much dependent on the DBMS. Some may not even allow an index on a calculated column, so speak to your DBA about that -- if you feel it would be of benefit, of course.

PS: I hope you are not offended by my simplistic examples using file cards and boxes. My experience with databases is now measured by the decade, but in my mind I still picture a tabletop covered with those little green plastic file boxes filled with note cards (or smaller boxes filled with cards). I find it a useful metaphor.